# Large charts on smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

I suddenly found out that in all the examples coming to my mind a (compact) smooth manifold has a "large" coordinate chart whose complement has positive codimension.

In other word, is it true that for any smooth compact manifold $M$ there exists a closed (probably singular) submanifold $N$ of positive codimension such that $M\setminus N$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? And the same question about topological manifolds with "diffeomorphic" replaced by "homeomorphic" and the complement of positive codimension replaced by some appropriate notion of "small" subset.

Comment: "..._connected_...."

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Did you mean that the condition of  codimension being non zero can be replaced by the condition that $M$ is connected?

Comment: @IvinBabu: I meant connectedness of $M$ is an essential hypothesis. (My oops for trying to be clever. It seems everyone involved was assuming connectedness, but it's worth being explicit for posterity. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can take for $N$ the [cut-locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_(Riemannian_manifold)) of a point. It is of zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I was gonna give the same example. But the cut locus is rarely a submanifold !

Comment: Sure. But the question asks for a (probably singular) manifold. The cut-locus seems to fit the bill.